# What mode or scale does Hans Zimmer dwell on in Dune?

Tags: scales, modes, intervals

I was listening to the Dune soundtrack just now as background music, and I noticed that it felt very modal. It keeps using the following series of intervals:

wholestep-halfstep-wholestep-halfstep-wholestep

This definitely isn't major, minor or any of the church modes, but I assume Hans Zimmer is not by any stretch the first person to do this. Is there a name for this arrangement of notes?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://songexploder.net/dune

Comment: I haven't heard the soundtrack, but just looking at those intervals, they'd match part of the ascending harmonic minor scale, starting from the submediant. For example, in C minor that's A B C D Eb F.

Comment: Good catch, gidds. He does them both upward and downward, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an answer to whole/half etc.:

The whole/half diminished scale. It uses eight notes in steps of alternating tone and semitone intervals. There is a sister to this - the half/whole diminished, which uses the obvious opposite.